# Swift compiler or framework bug?

Tags: arrays, swift

Below is some simple code to insert additional points into a 2D polygon. It never terminates (on Xcode 14.3, iOS 16.4.1(a)). The cause is explained in the comments — it appears that `polygon.count` returns the wrong value after `polygon.insert` when the insertion index equals `polygon.count`. This can't really be a compiler/framework bug surely, what am I missing?

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CompilerBug?
//

import UIKit
import simd

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        var polygon =  [SIMD3<Float>(1.345, 0.0, 0.002),SIMD3<Float>(1.181, 0.0, -0.171),SIMD3<Float>(1.185, 0.0, -0.206),SIMD3<Float>(1.141, 0.0, -0.255),SIMD3<Float>(1.121, 0.0, -0.257),SIMD3<Float>(0.848, 0.0, -0.636),SIMD3<Float>(0.777, 0.0, -0.604),SIMD3<Float>(0.692, 0.0, -0.532),SIMD3<Float>(0.677, 0.0, -0.5),SIMD3<Float>(0.6976719, 0.0, -0.46364594),SIMD3<Float>(0.903, 0.0, -0.188),SIMD3<Float>(1.1739755, 0.0, 0.12979852)]
        
        ViewController.addPoints(to: &polygon, every: 0.05)
    }

    static func addPoints(to polygon: inout [simd_float3], every d: Float) {
        let threshold = d * d
        var i = 0
        while i < polygon.count {
            let j = (i + 1) % polygon.count // "A"
            while polygon[i].distanceSquared2D(polygon[j]) > threshold {
                let new = simd_float3(x: (polygon[i].x + polygon[j].x) / 2.0,
                                      y: 0.0,
                                      z: (polygon[i].z + polygon[j].z) / 2.0)
                // when i+1 equals polygon.count, the subsequent call to polygon.count at "A"
                // after insertion returns the count prior to the insertion!
                polygon.insert(new, at: i + 1)
            }
            
            i += 1
        }
    }
}

extension simd_float3
{
    public func distanceSquared2D(_ b: simd_float3) -> Float {
        return (self.x - b.x) * (self.x - b.x) + (self.z - b.z) * (self.z - b.z)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear what you think your code is supposed to do, but if you instrument it with `print` statements you will see it is behaving logically and consistently:

```
    while i < polygon.count {
        print(i, polygon.count)
        let j = (i + 1) % polygon.count
        while polygon[i].distanceSquared2D(polygon[j]) > threshold {
            let new = simd_float3(x: (polygon[i].x + polygon[j].x) / 2.0,
                                  y: 0.0,
                                  z: (polygon[i].z + polygon[j].z) / 2.0)
            print("insert")
            polygon.insert(new, at: i + 1)
        }
        i += 1
    }
```

Every time the first `print` statement prints, we see that the number of times `"insert"` was printed and the increase in `polygon.count` are always the same. So one `insert` is one increment in `polygon.count`, which is as expected (and, I presume, desired).

Then when we reach `i` at 60 and `polygon.count` at 61, the inner `while` loop runs forever (we get a steady stream of `"insert"` without every coming round to the first `print` again) and so the app hangs.

So the only bug I see, if that's not the outcome you expect, is in your program itself. I suppose that the problem is that the condition

```
polygon[i].distanceSquared2D(polygon[j]) > threshold
```

just runs away with you, because neither `i` nor `j` changes and the insertions are now taking place at the `j` position.

Comment: Thanks @matt and apologies. Fix is simply to move the calculation of `j` into the inner loop. Been a long week.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would be something like that. This is why we have a debugger!